Cannot open the downloaded files after reinstalling the app
I recently developed an app which downloads pdfs from the server and saves them in a local storage.
I can open the file if I don't uninstall the app. If I reinstall the app then I cannot open the file.
Also I don't need access to other folders as I only target a folder ( folder That will be created ) in downloads folder.
I tried using various methods like mediastore or something new methods but cannot solve the issue.
 fun openPdfIntent(filePath: File, context: Context) {


        Log.i("Pdf", "openPdfIntent: ${filePath.absolutePath} ")
        val pdfIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
        val path =
            FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", filePath)
        pdfIntent.setDataAndType(
            path,
            "application/pdf"
        )
        pdfIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
        try {
            if (filePath.canRead()) {
                Log.i("Pdf", "openPdfIntent:  exists  and open")
                context.startActivity(pdfIntent)

            } else {
                pdfIntent.setDataAndType(
                    filePath.toUri(),
                    "application/pdf"
                )
                pdfIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
                Log.i("Pdf", "openPdfIntent: Doesn't exists ")
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Please Install Pdf Viewer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            if (filePath.exists()) {
                filePath.delete()
                Log.i("Pdf", "openPdfIntent: Deleted ")
            }
        }
    }


//function to download files.

 fun onDownload(
        index: Int,
        url: String,
        unitName: String,
        subjectName: String,
        context: Context,
    ) {
        viewModelScope.launch(IO) {
            val kDownloader = KDownloader.create(context)
            withContext(
                IO
            ) {

                this.async {

                    val req = kDownloader.newRequestBuilder(
                        url,
                        getFileDirectory(context).path + "/KIET PDFS/$subjectName",
                        "${subjectName}_${unitName}.pdf"
                    ).build()
                    kDownloader.enqueue(req,
                        onStart = {
                            Log.i("Downloads", "onDownload: Started for file $unitName.pdf")

                            downloadStatus[index] = downloadStatus[index].copy(
                                downloadProgress = DownloadProgress.Running
                            )
                        },
                        onCompleted = {
                            Log.i("Downloads", "onDownload: Success for $unitName.pdf ")
                            downloadStatus[index] = downloadStatus[index].copy(
                                downloadProgress = DownloadProgress.Success
                            )
                        }, onError = {
                            Log.i("Downloads", "onDownload: Error $it")
                            downloadStatus[
                                index
                            ] = downloadStatus[index].copy(
                                downloadProgress = DownloadProgress.Failed
                            )
                        }

                    )
                }.await()

            }

        }

    }

fun getFileDirectory(context: Context): File {
    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)!!
    } else {
        Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
    }

}

Android Manifest
<provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>

file_paths.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <external-path path="Android/data/${applicationId}/" name="files_root" />

    <root-path
        name="root"
        path="/" />

</paths>



If I reinstall the app then I cannot open the file.

Correct. Your app only has access to what is in Download/ where this specific app installation put those files into Download/. Any other app, including re-installed copies of your app, have no access to what your original app installation put there. And your app has no access to files that any other app put there.
This is why, for several years, Google has been steering developers towards the Storage Access Framework, such as ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT / ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument. These require no permissions and let the user choose content from a wider range of locations, including those where your app has no filesystem-level access.

yes but in my app I will have the exact filename/path of that document but I cannot access it after reinstallation. ActivityResultContracts will launch an intent to pick a document where as I have the document uri but not able to open it.Any solutions??

@Bharath_king77: "but I cannot access it after reinstallation" -- correct. You have no rights to that file. "Any solutions?" -- you will need to redesign your approach to device storage, to work within Android's security restrictions.

Any Solution for that, by extracting the working uri to pass to other apps to show them?

@Bharath_king77: There is no "working uri" for your new app installation.
